# Terminology for the parts of composition?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, terminology, relation-algebra

In function composition, binary relation composition, or more generally category theory, are there distinct names for the two things being composed?

If we have $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow Z$ we compose them to get $h: X \rightarrow Z$. This composition is usually written as $h = g \circ f$ but in many contexts it's written in the other direction, e.g. like this $h = f ; g$ or just $h = fg$

Is there a general name for $f$ and $g$ in composition which refer to their position but don't refer to the writing order? Something like "start morphism" and "end morphism"? "first morphism" and "second morphism"? "protomorphism" and "deuteromorphism"? If you're not aware of existing terminology for this, what do you think are appropriate names?

In CT there are already names for types of morphisms which avoid referring to order: Retraction/section for left/right inverse. Monic/epic for left/right cancellative. See [this blog post](https://blog.juliosong.com/linguistics/mathematics/category-theory-notes-9/) for more about how these terms can be confusing.

Comment: primocomposand?

Comment: @j-j-green note that I'm not asking for a term for *both* f and g. I'm asking for a name for f and a name for g. The former has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2847640/what-are-the-functions-that-make-composite-functions-called)

Comment: _primo_ latin prefix for _first_, so I was just suggesting a name for $f$, almost certainly a neologism though

Comment: ah I see. "composand" is a mouthful, though. (but, to be fair, so is morphism). The two prefixes from my post "proto" and "deutero" are Greek for first and second. What's Latin for second?

Comment: I think "factor" is commonly used, by analogy with ordinary multiplication. I wouldn't use ordinals though. "First" could refer to writing order too.

Comment: Latin second is _secondo_, and that would make a six-syllable word :-|  It would be brave to mix a Greek prefix with a Latin word, but not without precedent.

Comment: As in the chain rule, I'd say *outer* and *inner* morphism.

Comment: Premorphism and postmorphism? Like precompose and postcompose?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I like those, although it seems there is still some ambiguity see the discussion here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304339/terminology-question-precompose-vs-compose This is a surprisingly annoying terminological hole, imo